# inclusion-exclusion problem

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

How many base-k sequences are there of length n which contain
all k possible symbols?
I am trying to solve it using inclusion-exclusion. However, I am actually struggling with the part of counting the number of sequences while at least a symbol is used.
i.e. I am counting this:
$$|S_0\bigcup S_1\bigcup S_2...\bigcup S_{k-1}|= \sum_0^{k-1}|S_i|-\sum_0^{k-1}|S_i\bigcap S_j|$$+......+... where $S_i$denote the set of sequences which do not contain the symbol i. ($0 \le i\le k-1$)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the sum notations they use on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to see how they avoid two sets in the intersection being the same or having multiple times the same intersection in their sum.

Say S is the set of all base k sequences of length n and say the set of all base k sequences of length n that miss symbol i is called $S_i$. What you want to compute is $$|S\setminus \bigcup_{i=0}^{k-1}S_i|=k^n-\sum_{\emptyset\neq J\subset\{0,1,...,k-1\}}(-1)^{|J|-1}|\bigcap_{j\in J}S_j|=\\k^n-(|S_0|+|S_1|+...+|S_{k-1}|\\-|S_0\bigcap S_1|-...-|S_{k-2}\bigcap S_{k-1}|\\+|S_0\bigcap S_1\bigcap S_2|+...+|S_{k-3}\bigcap S_{k-2}\bigcap S_{k-1}|\\-...-...\\...\\+(-1)^{k-1}|S_0\bigcap S_1\bigcap ...\bigcap S_{k-1}|)$$

In the first row of the expanded sum every entry is $(k-1)^n$. In the second row every entry is $(k-2)^n$ and so on. The first row has $\binom{k}{1}$ entries, the second row has $\binom{k}{2}$ entries and so on. So
$$|S\setminus \bigcup_{i=0}^{k-1}S_i|=k^n-((k-1)^n\binom{k}{1}-(k-2)^n\binom{k}{2}+...+(-1)^{k-1}(k-k)^n\binom{k}{k})=\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^i(k-i)^n\binom{k}{i}$$ 
Not sure about further simplifications.

By the way this is also the number of surjective functions from the n element set [n] to the k element set [k] (your sequence has n elements and you want to map them to k characters in a surjective way).

Comment: shouldn't that be $+(k-2)^n$ ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. There is a pair of parentheses around the whole inclusion/exclusion sum and a minus sign in front so in the last expression the i=2 term in the sum is actually positive.